# Output results in a single table in console

Tags: sql, postgresql, jetbrains-ide

I'm running the below code using POSTGRESQL in Jetbrains.  I'm trying to output the results in a neat 2 column table (QUARTER, RESULTS) INSIDE the console.  When I run the below code, it comes back, but in separate tables, making it annoying to have to consolidate the results from each.  Is there a way to get multiple results in the same table so I can copy and paste the results INSIDE the console?  Thank you

I'm running

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  CUSTOMER)  as Q216 FROM(
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE
WHERE CUSTOMER IN ( SELECT   CUSTOMER
                           FROM     temp_08.Unemployment
                           WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE > '3/31/2016'))



SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  CUSTOMER)  as Q116 FROM(
SELECT  *
FROM    temp_08.COF
WHERE CUSTOMER IN ( SELECT   CUSTOMER
                           FROM     temp_08.Unemployment
                           WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE between '12/31/2015' and '3/31/2016'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to have the result of each query as it's own column?

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  CUSTOMER)
          FROM (SELECT *
                 FROM TABLE
                 WHERE CUSTOMER IN ( SELECT CUSTOMER
                                       FROM temp_08.Unemployment
                                       WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE > '3/31/2016'
                                   )
               )
       ) AS Q216

      ,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER)
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM temp_08.COF
                  WHERE CUSTOMER IN (SELECT CUSTOMER
                                       FROM temp_08.Unemployment
                                       WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE between '12/31/2015' and '3/31/2016'
                                     )
               )
       ) AS Q116
```